Why doesn't it work both ways?
I am currently trying to find a way to calculate the total number of combinations of different loops I can get so that I can calculate the probability of something. The question starts out with $11$ people who are playing Secret Santa , in which each person gets given another person (you only know who you are giving the gift to, not who is giving you a gift or anything else like that). Given that no person has to gift to themselves, and each person gets one and only one gift, what is the probability that every person sits on a single loop, for example; $$p_1\rightarrow p_2\rightarrow p_3\rightarrow ...\rightarrow p_{11}\rightarrow p_1 $$
but not; $$p_1\rightarrow p_2\rightarrow p_1\space|\space p_3\rightarrow...\rightarrow p_{11}\rightarrow p_3$$
To start, I decided to lower the number of people ($n$) from $11$ to $6$, so I can grapple with an easier problem but not one that's trivial. For reference I will denote the number of loops as $L$, a specific loop combination (such as a loop of $4$ and a loop of $2$) as $a|b|c...$, up to however many loops there are (such as $4|2$, or for $n=11$, $6|3|2$). It will always be the case that $a+b+c+...=n$. Additionally, instead of writing $p_1\rightarrow p_2$, I will just write $[1,2]$, so that way I am thinking in terms of lists instead of who is gifting to who. The $p_{11}\rightarrow p_1$ will be ignored as it is trivial, instead, the end of a list is assumed to link back to the start. ($[1,2,...11]$ means $11$ goes back to $1$).
My working: consider a loop $4|2$, such as $[1,2,3,4] \space|\space [5,6]$. If I lock the $[5,6]$ loop and imaging all the rearrangements of $[1,2,3,4]$. One thing to note is that since it is a loop, I could "shift it along 1", and get $[4,1,2,3]$, which is still the same loop. If we fix the smallest number to the front of a loop, such as one $1$, we remove the double up loops. Continuing on, the loops we can get from rearranging $[1,2,3,4]$ are $$[1,2,3,4], [1,2,4,3], [1,3,2,4], [1,3,4,2], [1,4,2,3], [1,4,3,2]$$
of which there are $6$ ($(4-1)!$).
So, there are $6$ loop arrangements for each loop of $2$, and since the number of loops with length $2$ is ${n\choose2}={6\choose2}=15$, the total number of loops in the form $4|2$ should be $6\times15=90$. Generalizing this, for any $2$ loops $a|b$, we should expect that the total number of combinations to be $(a-1)!{n\choose b}$
My problem:
What is don't understand is why I get different results for $a|b$ compared to $b|a$. There still the same loops so what order I consider these loops in should have no effect on the total number of combinations, yet if $a\neq b$, then $(a-1)!{n\choose b}\neq (b-1)!{n\choose a}$. For example, we said that the total combinations of $4|2$ is $90$, but for $2|4$ one would get $15$, which makes no sense. But I don't know where I've gone wrong. Each step makes perfect sense in my head, but it doesn't work out?
Any help is appreciated.

Notes about more standard vocabulary: (0) You are talking about permutations without any fixed points, a.k.a. derangements. (1) What you call a loop is usually called a cycle, and a combination of disjoint cycles is organized by its cycle type (conjugacy class in the symmetric group). (2) You've reinvented cycle notation from scratch, including the fact that a $k$-cycle has $k$ distinct ways to represent it. Congratulations!

This might help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130457/the-distribution-of-cycle-length-in-random-derangement

Downvoted for a clickbait title.

I just deleted the bottom half of my answer.  As indicated by the comments of tkf, following my answer, that portion of my answer was wrong.

The number of 2-loops is in fact $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{2},~$ because once the two elements $~r,s~$ are chosen, each of the $~2!~$ ways of listing $~[r,s]~$ result in the same permutation.
For $~k > 2,~$ the formula is no longer valid.  For example, consider the $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{3}~$ ways of choosing the elements $~r,s,t.$
Then the $~3!~$ different ways of internally permuting $~r,s,t,~$ which are shown below, do not all represent the same permutation:
$$[r,s,t], [r,t,s], [s,r,t], [s,t,r], [t,r,s], [t,s,r].$$

Edit: As pointed out by @Dodezv in comments, there is a closed form solution.  This answer has been reorganised accordingly.
The notation $!n$ denotes the number of derangements of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$.Let $p_n$ denote the probability that a  derangent is an $n$-cycle.  Then $$p_n=\frac{(n-1)!}{!n}$$
Let $A_i$ denote the set of permutations of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ that fix the element $i$.  Then the derangements are precisely the permutations not in the $A_i$ and we can use the inclusion-exclusion principle:
$$!n=\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,\cdots,n\}}(-1)^{|S|}\left|\bigcap_{i\in S} A_i \right|\\
=\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n\choose r} (n-r)! $$
as there are ${n\choose r}$ choices of set $S$ of size $r$, and the corresponding intersection has $(n-r)!$ elements.
Thus $$p_n=\frac{(n-1)!}{!n}\\\\\qquad\quad=\frac1n \frac1{\sum_{r=0}^n \frac {(-1)^r}{r!}},$$ which converges asymptotically to $\frac en$ as $n\to \infty$.
So we can estimate $p_{11}$ by $\frac e{11}=0.24711652986$ and this turns out to be correct to $8$ decimal places, as we shall see.
To get an exact expression, not involving a sum, we may note that: $$\left|!n-\frac{n!}e\right|=\left| \sum_{r=n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^rn!}{r!}\right|<\sum_{r=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^r=\frac1n$$
Thus for $n\geq 3$ we have that $\frac{n!}e$ differs from the integer $!n$ by less than $\frac12$, so $\frac{n!}e+\frac12$ lies between the integers $!n$ and $!n+1$.  We conclude $$!n=\left\lfloor\frac{n!}e+\frac12\right\rfloor.$$
(The cases $n=1,2$ can be checked independently).
Thus $$p_n=\frac{(n-1)!}{\left\lfloor\frac{n!}e+\frac12\right\rfloor}$$
In particular, $p_{11}=0.24711653116,$ agreeing with our previous estimate to $8$ decimal places.
Alternatively: Use the recurrence relation $$!n=(n-1)\left(!(n-1)+!(n-2)\right)$$
The identity follows from the following reasoning:  Any derangement of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ must send $1$ to one of the $n-1$ other elements. If this element is sent back to $1$, then we get a derangement of $n-2$ elements by ignoring $1$ and its image.  Otherwise we can remove $1$ from the cycle it is in, and get a derangement on $n-1$ elements.  Conversely we can recover the original derangement from the image of $1$, and the derangement of $n-1$ or $n-2$ elements.
Let $q_n=\frac1{p_n}=\frac{!n}{(n-1)!}$.  The recurrence relation therefore becomes: $$q_n=q_{n-1}+\frac{q_{n-2}}{n-2}$$
This again gives us $p_{11}=\frac1{q_{11}}\approx0.24711653116$.

Just FYI: $!n$ is OEIS sequence A000166 and according to OEIS has the closed form $\lfloor{\frac{n!}{e}+\frac12}\rfloor$, but I haven't seen the proof.

The source of your error:  you drew the wrong generalization.  Specifically, you neglected to note the factor of $(2-1)!=1$ in counting the number of $2-$cycles on a set of order $2$.  Of course, in the case of $2-$cycles, that factor changes nothing.
In general:  there are $(n-1)!$ $n-$cycles on a set of order $n$.  Indeed, we have $n-1$ options for $1$, leaving $n-2$ options for whichever value was attached to $1$, and so on.  You correctly showed this in the case of your $4-$cycle.  Thus, at least if $a\neq b$, we can count the number of $a|b$ cases, to use your notation, as $\binom na\times (a-1)!\times (b-1)!$   Of course, $n=a+b$ so $\binom na=\binom nb$ making the expression fully symmetric as you expected.
That matches your result for the case $4|2$, as it should.
If $a=b$ you have an additional symmetry arising from the fact that you can switch the two cycles.  Thus you must divide by $2$ in this case.  If you have more cycles, then these "additional symmetries" get more and more complicated, making it hard to write down such simple formulas.
